# XBMC won't load any plugins and the browse plugins are not there

Tags: kodi

I've installed the latest svn build of XBMC on Ubuntu using

```
ppa:team-xbmc-svn/ppa
```

Works nicely, except for plugins, which don't work at all. My plugins in ~/.xbmc/plugins/video is not there, and there is no Videos->Add source->Browse->Video plugin anymore.

What has happened and how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Without providing any more information, you can try the generic troubleshooting.
Try running `sudo apt-get upgrade` to upgrade your packages.
Try a different repo, perhaps.

Comment: Actually, the problem turned out to be by design. That's the future, counted from now. http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?t=79495